# Writing global languages to MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, globalization

I am using PHP and MySQL innodb (PDO) below is structure of table.

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `feed_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `link` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `pubdate` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `loaddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `uniqid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `source` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`feed_id`),
 KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`),
 KEY `link` (`link`,`uniqid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
$DB->sql = "INSERT INTO feed_articles (feed_id,title,link,description,image,video,audio,pubdate,loaddate,uniqid,source) VALUES ";
$DB->sql .= "(".$pfid.",".$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["title"])
                     .",".$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["link"])
                     .",".$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["desc"])
                     .",".(isset($RSSarticles[$i]["image"])?$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["image"]):"''")
                     .",".(isset($RSSarticles[$i]["video"])?$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["video"]):"''")
                     .",".(isset($RSSarticles[$i]["audio"])?$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["audio"]):"''")
                     .",".$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["date"])
                     .",CURRENT_DATE,"
                     .$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["id"])
                     .",".$DB->quote($RSSarticles[$i]["source"])
                                                .") ";

$DB->execute($DB->sql);
```

The issue is it is not writing other languages characters correctly it is doing some conversion and write to DB. If i directly copy paste in database then it is fine. but using PHP i am not sure what is going wrong.

Anybody have some idea how i should get it work for all languages like chinese/german/russian

Update for each connection i am doing this.:

```
    function connection($server,$usernamedb,$passworddb,$dbname)
    {
        //$this->id = @mysql_connect($server, $usernamedb, $passworddb);
        $this->id = mysql_connect($server, $usernamedb, $passworddb);

        if ($this->id)
        {
            $this->selectDB($dbname);
            $this->setUtf8();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->warning();
        }
    }
function setUtf8()
    {
        $this->execute("SET NAMES 'utf8' ");
        $this->execute("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8' ");
    }
```

but i observed one thing in my php configuration default_charset = iso-8859-1 is this causing issue.??

Database is UTF8 Format so no problem there.

Thank you.
Mona

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the connection charset to utf8 using [mysqli::set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php). And please check if the content of the `$RSSarticles` array is indeed utf8 - if not you'll have to convert it yourself first.

Comment: Hi Louis, Thank you for answer. I have provided more details in my question plz have look..

Comment: Ok. And is your data utf8? (The data you're going to save to the database)

Comment: yes Louis it is in utf8 format. Just wondering is there anything i can do like conversion if data is not in UTF format before sending to mysql.

Comment: You can - Use [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and [mb_convert_variables](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-variables.php).

Answer (score 0):

edited to match the update:

yes, you should set the configuration setting `default_charset` to UTF-8.
Always try to use only one charset in all parts of an application (website code, client side code, DB)

original answer below:

---

you have found one of the obscurer obstacles when dealing with UTF-8, PHP and Databases.

I assume your input data is in UTF-8?

even if your PHP script, your DB tables and fields are in UTF-8, you still need to tell your DB adapter to use UTF-8 on the transport and connection.

the easiest way to achieve this is using the `SET NAMES` statement after you established your DB connection.

```
$DB->execute("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

should be enough

Comment: Hi cypherabe, Thank you for answer. I have provided more details in my question plz have look..

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly set your database default character set  to utf8
using following command

ALTER DATABASE db_name
 DEFAULT  CHARACTER SET   utf8  
  and also set character set in   php  file  using following code  in first line of php

 <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi Alok, Thank you for answer. I have provided more details in my question plz have look..